# Get total order value on success.phtml page using onepage checkout

Tags: magento2.2, onepage-checkout, order-success-page

I posted this question:
[How can i get the order total value on success page easily? Magento 2.2](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/272681/how-can-i-get-the-order-total-value-on-success-page-easily-magento-2-2)
But it never got resolved. Unsure how to rerequest help about it. But I need to get it solved.

I am using magento 2.2.1

The page in question is using:

```
$block: \Magento\Checkout\Block\Onepage\Success
```

I am able to get the OrderID but not the grandtotal. I have tried all suggestions I have been able to recreate found on google and on this forum.

I need the grandtotal for creating a postback to the facebook pixel.

I am able to get the orderid using: `$lastOrderId = $block->getOrderId();`

And I have tried things like:

```
$lastOrderId = $block->getOrderId();
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$order = $objectManager->create('Magento\Sales\Model\Order')->load($lastOrderId);
echo "order id: ". $lastOrderId;
echo $order->getGrandTotal();
```

Any suggestions?
Would very much appreciate some help

Answer (score 0):

I had made similar functionality as I need to send the order information to the third party marketing platform from a successful page.

The following script is working for me.

```
if ($block->getOrderId()):
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$lid = $block->getOrderId();
$order = $objectManager->create('Magento\Sales\Model\Order')->load($lid);
$amount = number_format($order->getGrandTotal(),2);
```

endif;

if you're still facing any issue. let's have skype screen sharing.

You can add me in skype: samumaretiya

Thanks,
Sam

Comment: Sadly it did not work. The amount shows zero. But I added you to skype :)

Answer (score 0):

A little late, but may help someone else. The above solution doesn't work because loadByIncrementId must be used on this line:

$order = $objectManager->create('Magento\Sales\Model\Order')->loadByIncrementId ($lid);